# Clear array of structs in Rust

Tags: c, arrays, struct, rust, migration

I'm researching the possibility of porting a C program over to Rust.
Is it possible to duplicate this C code in Rust?

```
struct myStruct {
  int  var1;
  int  var2;
  char var3[32];
  int  var4;
}

int main() {
  struct myStruct myArray[1000];
  bzero((char*) myArray,sizeof(myArray)); // clear entire array
  myArray[0].var1 = 42;
  sprintf(myArray[0].var3, "Hello World!");
 /* other code here */
}
```

I've tried various methods and all come up with compile errors.

Comment: Rust and C have very different programming paradigms. So you cannot (or should not) blindly translate one to another, but rather reimplement the required feature based on the principles of the target language.

Comment: I understand that.  I've read about Rust and played with it some, I'm just not figuring out how to "reimplement" the array of structs.  I understand it needs to be Mutable and how ownership works, but clearing it to nulls seems to not be at all obvious in my searches.  Even the answers given to other questions about that don't compile.

Comment: "Array of structs" serves no purpose by itself. It is a just a data structure used to implement a specific functionality. In Rust you might want to use some other data structure for that functionality.

Comment: The Array is declared in line 1 of main and then zeroed out on the next line.  That array is now available to store 1000 rows of myStruct.  Not sure how it "serves no purpose".  The program will slowly fill it up as data becomes available.  It's like a database in memory that can easily be searched and indexed.  If an Array is not designed for that purpose, can you explain what you would use to implement that functionality?

Comment: FYI, here is a Rust equivalent: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=90c48c082a751d349b7723a847511975

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your `struct` is trivially copyable and only contains types whose default value would be 0, you can simply derive `Default` and use an array literal:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Default)]
struct MyStruct {
    var1: i64,
    var2: [u8; 32],
    var3: i64,
    var4: i64,
}

fn main() {
    let array = [MyStruct::default(); 1000];
}
```

A structure that is 0-initializable with `bzero` is most likely always going to be `Copy` so you can use an array literal.

Note however that this is very likely going to be unidiomatic in Rust, where using `Vec` would probably be considered better, as explained in [bk2204's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60662913/2733851).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of allocating a large array and zeroing items, it may be better to use something like a `Vec` and insert items into it as you create them.  Rust doesn't generally use the zero-initialized structure philosophy, so you'll be able to create items as you need them, and you'll be guaranteed that only valid items are stored in your structure.  While it's common in C to stuff uninitialized or partially initialized data into a data structure, Rust prefers to have only fully initialized, valid data, which helps preserve safety guarantees.

You may want to have your structure have a constructor to ensure it's fully initialized, plus accessors.  Or, if you aren't exposing the structure to other code, you can just manually initialize it.

If you know well how many items you need to allocate up front, you can use `Vec::with_capacity` to perform the allocation up front.  This can be helpful even if your estimate is a little too low, since the structure can expand at runtime, just less efficiently.  Depending on your allocation behavior, a `VecDeque` could be beneficial instead, but with the downside that you can't convert it into a slice.

If your data structure is more like a hash map or a set, whether sorted or not, then there are collections under `std::collections` which will likely meet your needs better.